# Preserving data over multiple form submission

Tags: php, html, sql, postgresql

I am building a web service in which a user can login to a backend, submit a form and then other users will be able to see this information on the front-end of the web service.

The data is submitted to the PostgreSQL database fine BUT on the second submission of the form (users can go back to the form and update their information if neccessary) if there is a blank field in the form, the existing data in the form is overwritten with blank data.

How can I avoid this? I think it would be good to populate the form fields with data from the database and allow the user to edit the form like that but I am unsure how to implement this using PHP. At the moment a user would have to fill out the form in full over and over to prevent this kind of data loss.

Could someone give me an idea or point me in the right direction?

Comment: If it's not sensitive information, store it in the user's session via a cookie or a server-side session. Otherwise store it in the DB and when the next form is displayed pre-fill it with the data you retrieve from the DB during form rendering or (if you want to be fancy) a placeholder in JavaScript that shows that the field already has a value without revealing what it is.

Comment: _if there is a blank field in the form, the existing data in the form is overwritten with blank data._ You mean the existing data in the **database** right?

Comment: @SandyLee yes that's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pre-fill the form fields with earlier entries from the DB

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $fname;?>" name="first_name" id="first_name" />
```

Comment: Ahh brilliant thank you. So upon save this will write the `value` to the database and if unedited will of course remain the same? Will implement and I'm expecting to give you the correct answer.

Comment: There will be a large amount of data submitted. Is there a way I can grab all the data from the relevant data table and then simply echo it as a value rather than having a looong list of variables, which represent each individual data column, at the top of the script?

Comment: use an array. Lets say your data from the DB is stored in an array called $results;

`<input type="text" value="<?php echo $results['fname'];?>" name="first_name" id="first_name" />
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $results['lname'];?>" name="last_name" id="last_name" />
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $results['email'];?>" name="email" id="email" />
`
and so forth. Basically if the user doesn't change the value of the form, the previous stored value will be used.
Let me know if you need anything else :)